# Precisely map World Position to UV Texture-Coordinates (OpenGL Compute Shader)

Tags: opengl, mapping, textures

I need help to precisely sample from my 3D Texture in the OpenGL (4.5) Compute Shader given a world position (within the domain of the texture dimensions). More precisely, I need help with my `uv()` function which maps world coordinates to the exact corresponding texture coordinates.

I want linear interpolation of the data, so my current approach uses `texture()`. But this results in errors around `0.001` compared to the expected values.
**However,** if I use `texelFetch()` and `mix()` to manually mimick the linear interpolation of `texture()` as stated in the [specification](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec45.core.pdf) (p. 248), I can reduce the error to `0.0000001` (which is desired). You can see an example of how I implemented it below in the Code section.

This is the function which I currently use inside the Compute Shader to calculate my uv-coordinates:

```c
vec3 uv(const vec3 position) {
  return (position + 0.5) / textureSize(tex[0], 0);
}
```

Though this one is often suggested across the internet, my results are not perfectly aligned.

#### Example

To elaborate, I have floating point data stored in a Texture as `GL_RGB32F`. For simplicity my example here uses scalar `GL_R32F`. The data has dimensions of, e.g., 20x20x20 (but can be arbitrary). I operate in the data domain `[0, 19]^3` and want to exactly map my current position to the texture domain `[0, 1]^3` to index the data at this position.

I have a test texture which alternates between `0` and `1` on the x-axis and therefore should interpolate for `vec3(2.2, 0, 0)` to `0.2`.

As stated above, I tested `texture()` and `texelFetch()` + `mix()`. My manual interpolation evaluates to `0.200000003` which is fine. But calling `texture()` evaluates to `0.199218750`, a quite high error compared. Strangely, manual interpolation and automatic interpolation evaluate to the same (correct) value for integer positions and the mid between integer positions (e.g., for `vec3(2.0, 0, 0)`, `vec3(2.5, 0, 0)` and `vec3(3.0, 0, 0)`).

A visual example with actual calculated values:

```
uv(x, y, z) = ((x, y, z) + 0.5) / (20, 20, 20)

19|                    1 |           
  |                      |           
..|               uv   ..|           
  |  (2.2, 3.0)   ===>   |  (0.135, 0.175)
1 |      x               |      x    
  |___________           |___________
0    1  ..  19         0            1
```

#### Code

I use C++, OpenGL 4.5 and globjects as a wrapper for OpenGL. The texture buffers are created and configured as depicted below.

```cpp
// Texture buffer creation
t = globjects::Texture::createDefault(gl::GLenum::GL_TEXTURE_3D);

t->setParameter(gl::GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl::GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
t->setParameter(gl::GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl::GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
t->setParameter(gl::GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, gl::GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

t->setParameter(gl::GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl::GL_LINEAR);
t->setParameter(gl::GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl::GL_LINEAR);
```

The Compute Shader is invocated.

```cpp
// datatex holds image information
t->image3D(0, gl::GL_RGB32F, datatex->dimensions, 0, gl::GL_RGB, gl::GL_FLOAT, (const uint8_t*) datatex->data());

// ... (Make texture resident)

gl::glDispatchCompute(1, 1, 1);

// ... (Make texture not resident)
```

The Compute Shader, summarized to the important parts, is as follows:

```c
#version 450
#extension GL_ARB_bindless_texture : enable

layout(local_size_x = 1, local_size_y = 1, local_size_z = 1) in;

layout(binding=0) uniform samplers
{
  sampler3D tex[1];
};

vec3 uv(const vec3 position) {
  return (position + 0.5) / textureSize(tex[0], 0);
}

void main() {
  // Automatic interpolation
  vec4 correct1 = texture(tex[0], uv(vec3(2.0,0,0), 0);
  vec4 correct2 = texture(tex[0], uv(vec3(2.5,0,0), 0);
  vec4 correct3 = texture(tex[0], uv(vec3(3.0,0,0), 0);
  vec4 wrong    = texture(tex[0], uv(vec3(2.1,0,0), 0);

  // Manual interpolation on x-axis
  vec3 pos = vec3(2.1,0,0);
  vec4 v0  = texelFetch(tex[0], ivec3(floor(pos.x), pos.yz), 0);
  vec4 v1  = texelFetch(tex[0], ivec3(ceil(pos.x), pos.yz), 0);
  vec4 correct4 = mix(v0, v1, fract(pos.x));
}
```

I'd love your input, I'm at my end.. Thanks!

#### System

Also, I'm trying to achieve this on an NVIDIA GPU.

Comment: Your math is correct. My guess is that the interpolation in the texture mapping unit uses lower precision than the math in the shader. I don't remember OpenGL spec saying anything specific about the precision of the texture interpolation.

Comment: I didn't want to believe it, but you're right. I only looked into the OpenGL Specs before but there they didn't state anything like that. Looking into D3D11 or Vulkan Specs, they describe, that the GPU's Texture Units only need 8bit precision in the fraction to internally resolve normalized uv-coordinates back to texture-sized coordinates. This also explaines why I'm able to accurately access integer and half-integer coordinates, as they are perfectly fine representable with 8 bit precision inthe fraction. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The texture units of GPUs are only needed to sample with 8bit precision in the fraction as of the D3D11 specs. This explains the small error which does not happen on (normalized) integer or mid-integer coordinates.

The fractional precision can also be queried in Vulkan via subTexelPrecisionBits and the online Vulkan database shows that there is no GPU as of today which offers more than 8 bits of precision in the fraction during sampling.

Performing linear interpolation in the shader itself offers the full float32 precision.